# MessageManager Messages Not Showing Added Via Controller?

Tags: magento2

I have a controller that extends a class which is extending \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action

I am expecting the following to show a message on the page, what am I doing wrong?

```
    $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Test message'));
    return $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
```

Edit: The messages do not show on the home page which I was redirecting to. However, when I did a catalogue search three of my success messages displayed that I had been trying to add. This leads me to believe that it is a layout problem.

Comment: Which version you are using of magento2 ?

Comment: Magento ver. 2.2.0-dev